# Efficient way to change the sort index of an element

Tags: java, algorithm, google-app-engine, data-structures, google-cloud-datastore

I have a very big list of element in my non-sql database.

Every element has a sort order from 1 to N. This sort order specifies how the results appear on the forms.

When in the UI triggers a change of order (put element i in position j) I need to update all the entities between. If the element 1 becomes the lastest, I need to make N updates.

Is there an efficient way to make this operation less costly? Is there an smart way to index the sort value?

Some considerations:

- I'm re-designing my application so I can afford to reindex the entities with a smarter solution.
- The cost of a write (update) is +-4 times bigger than a fetch (read 1 entity).
- The list is big, does not fit in memory.

Comment: As far as javascript goes, the less changes to the DOM you make, the better. It would be best if you could determine your form elements' orders before using appendChild.

Comment: First, do the elements have to be actual random-access indices, or just in monotonically-increasing order. (For example, if you could add two elements at position 2.333 and 2.666 and have them show up between 2 and 3, would that be good enough, or do you need to know that the one at position 3 is actually the 4th one rather than the 6th?)

Comment: Second, I'm assuming lookups have to be faster than inserts/moves, but if that's not true, that opens up a wider range of answers, so it's worth asking…

Comment: Third, are you keeping a list/dict/whatever of elements with (among other members) sort orders, plus a separate list/array/whatever in sort order (like a SQL-style index)? What are the actual data structures you're using?

Comment: What language? You got multiple of them listed.

Comment: And one last question: Does the efficiency really make any difference here? I'd bet that the DOM changes in the UI take so much more time than an O(N) reordering in your code that it scarcely matters. Do you have a reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: If I have to reindex 2 million entities in a datastore that charges me for every operation, that´s costly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reindex your entities. Set order property to double.
2. Every time a user moves an entity to a new position, assign it a new order property between the other two entities:

   entityA.setOrder((entityB.getOrder() + entityC.getOrder())/2);
3. Save entity A (property "order" should be indexed).
4. When a user requests entities from 10000 to 10200, build a Query on your order property with a sort order. Retrieve results from 10000 to 10200:

   datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withOffset(10000).limit(200));
5. Never reindex your entities again. Datastore does it for you every time you save an entity.

Comment: I agree, this is pretty much the same as what I was suggesting.  While doubles are indeed sparse, assuming you have infinite space is courting disaster.  Let's say he makes a wildly successful twitter clone and has a trillion entities (about 3 days of tweets if each tweet was an entity).  If he sorts once per second, yes, at the worst case he could hit a collision in about 8 years.  However in a month, when he has 8x the data, it would only take him 1 year to hit the collision.  It really depends how much data and how much sorting he's doing, but it's not impossible.

Comment: You are suggesting that his app will have something like 18,000,000 of TRILLIONS of records in about a year? We can safely assume it's not going to happen. If hits just one trillion, he'll be tweeting from his yacht in France.

Comment: I wish! The practical answer is no, I won't have trillions of entities but the question is which is the most efficient way. We can discuss a lot about what is efficiency. I'd say the best solution is the one it can handle more data with less collisions with the minimum ops.

Comment: There will be no collisions in my solution, and there is zero cost: no extra reads or writes relative to just saving your entity with a new order number. It won't get more efficient than that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're storing entities in the GAE datastore and letting the datastore index the entities for you.  The datastore uses a linked-list like index, but you don't have access to the linked list.

I don't think there's a perfect mechanism, but instead of sorting your N items from 1..N, I'd use a large sparse set of numbers (for example, use floats), and evenly distribute your entities across that range.  Whenever you sort an item, simply generate a new index value that exists between the two new neighbors.

If you hit a worst case scenario, where the neighbors are too close together, generate new indexes for the neighbors, and so forth.  A more advanced system might guarantee that there is a minimum amount of space between entities after every re-sort, and reindex a few extra neighbors proactively.

Comment: Appengine stores all floats as doubles. I am not sure what you mean by "too close together". It would take him a billion years to run out of double's precision.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, there is not other alternative with your current model. Like an indexed collection, you have to "re-index" elements when you move them: decrement or increment part of the collection

Change the model could be a solution for your requirements. You could try to design it like a linked list , where remove/move/insert operations are "cheaper". Every element knows its next (simple) or next and previous elements(Double)

Comment: If I use a linked list strategy (I guess you mean by pointing to the next element) then the cost is 2 operations but then at every sort I need to load all the data and then rebuild the list so I can then sort it.

Comment: @Jordi can you explain what you mean by "loading" all the data and "rebuilding" the list?

Comment: When I want to display the elements from 10000 to 10200 sorted, assuming I don't have the elements phisically sorted, I need to retrieve the whole data, construct the linked list, go thru it and get those elements. In your solution is cheap to update but not ideal to read.

Comment: @Jordi, I see your point, but with your current design removing the first element or moving it to the end has the same effect.

Comment: I agree. Your solution is 4 times cheaper than mine,since reads are 4 times cheaper but still O(N).

Comment: @Jordi, do you have to show the order in your form? is your data store in a filesystem?

Comment: my data store is: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview
you can find details of the implemetation in he 2011 google I/O, bigtable.

Comment: @Jordi I just tested the solution with double. The amount of elements you can move between two numbers is quite low. From 1000000 to 1000001 only 34 without collision (64bit double 15 digits precision). It seems a waste of space in my opinion. It is better to use int or long datatypes with gaps (100 steps), and reindex on collision only.

Comment: @Victor. Datastore stores all values as 64 bits.  You save nothing by going with int or longs. Also, there will be no collision for thousands of years, but if you want, you can add a solution which takes a few lines of code. Way cheaper than to reindex.

Answer (score -2):

you can separate sort order & UI data from other bulky data in each entity. the later can remain unchanged.

hmm, if you have this:

```
entitles = [bigdata1, bigdata2, bigdata3, ...]
order_numbers = [2, 3, 1, ...]
```

order_numbers can be the result of a sort or arbitrarily user defined values.

then you have

```
display_order = [2, 0, 1, ...]
```

means bigdata3 is displayed first. If UI wants to change the orders in anyway, only order_numbers and display_order need changes, not entitles. This is my understanding.

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your answer. Can you extend it?

Comment: The question is not about UI. It's about efficient way to reindex 2 million entities in a datastore.

Comment: quote: When in the UI triggers a change of order (put element i in position j) I need to update all the entities between. If the element 1 becomes the lastest, I need to make N updates. What values in an entities need to be updated? it could not be everything. give me an example.